# Keras Embedding : indices[15,138] = 12635 not in [0, 12635)

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras

I have defined my model as:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(12635, 300, weights=[embedding_matrix],
                   input_length=140, trainable=False))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(300))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

However, on training the model, I get the error that indices[15, 138] = 12635 is not in [0, 12635). How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that your inputs are expected to be in the range [0, input_dim) where input_dim is the parameter you passed to the embedding layer. But the data that you are passing in has a larger value.

Before passing in the input check that all your input values are less than input_dim. It just looks like an off-by-one error, where the size of your vocabulary is 12635 + 1. Note that it is a common practice to exclude the value 0 as a token id. Check whether your tokenizer is reserving 0 and then then using "token index + 1" as the token id.

Comment: Yep, the 0 token_id was throwing an error. Fixed it now, thanks a lot!

Comment: If you consider the question as answered, please marked it so by accepting the answer. Otherwise it will still show up in the list of unanswered questions. Thanks.